# Dynamic Model & Pattern with Regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I want to create a completely dynamic Form which is generated via ng-repeat and every input has its own ng-pattern(regex) values.

Basically I got a string like this:

```
TestView.Txt.Num6_CLX.Txt3_ALB.Num3,2_CLX
```

So I would split the String to an array:

My Filter

```
.filter('split', function () {
    return function (input, splitChar, splitIndex) {
        if (input != undefined && input != null && splitIndex) {
            return input.split(splitChar)[splitIndex];
        } else if (input != undefined && input != null && !splitIndex) {
            return input.split(splitChar);
        }
    };
})
```

Then calling this in my controller

```
$scope.fields = $filter('split')($stateParams.fields, '.');
```

Leaving me this:

```
["TestView", "Txt", "Num6_CLX", "Txt3_ALB", "Num3,2_CLX"]
```

Now the First Part ("TestView") is the name of the View

So I start my ng-repeat at index 1 like this:

My Filter:

```
.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="item item-input" ng-repeat="item in fields | startFrom : 1  track by $index">
```

So I have defined the  `$scope.values = {};` and now generate the Input Fields with the ng-repeat:

```
<input type="text" ng-enter="check(values, $index)" ng-model="values['field_'+$index]"/>
```

Now when I trigger `ng-enter` with 1234 in field like this:

```
$scope.check = function (data, index) {
         console.log(data['field_' + index]);
         console.log($scope.values['field_' + index]);
}
```

Result is both values are undefined... !

The 2nd Problem is I want to match the entered Data with the dynamic Regex from the earlier splitted fields. `"Num3,2_CLX"` This part would mean it should be a max of 3digits before comma and max 2 after.

First I split at the `'_'`, then I substring after 3 characters (field definition) to get the regex definition. And then I would `replace the x,y` values in the Regex string to match against the input value

```
var pattern = '/^(?!\.?$)\d{0,x}(\.\d{0,y})?$/g';
            var values = field.split('_');
            var numbers = values[0].substring(3);
            if (numbers.indexOf(',') > -1) {
                pattern.replace('x', numbers.split(',')[0]);
                pattern.replace('y', numbers.split(',')[1]);
                regex = new RegExp(pattern);
            } else {
                pattern.replace('x', numbers);
                pattern.replace('y', 0);
                regex = new RegExp(pattern);
            }
            console.log(regex);
            console.log($scope.values['field_' + index].match(regex));
```

Comment: values is an array or object ? [] or {}

Comment: values is the String posten at the beginning